# Edit Character Limit is keeping me from removing an emoticon

Tags: support, answers, edits

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5463223/2483138) has an emoticon.  I want to remove it because it doesn't belong.  It seems like an edit, but it's less than 6 characters.  I guess I could special-flag it and ask a mod to make the change, but that seems like shotgunning a fly.

What's the right thing to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pick one:

1. Come up with a more meaningful edit to the post, in addition to just removing those two characters
2. Do nothing.

Answer (score 5):

This is not something worthy of a moderator flag, so please don't use that to ask us to step in and edit this.

If you really want to remove it, then you'll need to make a substantial edit to it or do nothing.

I've gone ahead and removed the emoticon and formatted the code.